# Ruby on Rails with Cassandra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra

I have a host with 4 docker containers. On three containers, I have set up Cassandra nodes.
On the fourth container, I have a Ruby on Rails application running and I am trying to connect to the Cassandra cluster from it.

I get the following error while trying to connect:

```
require 'cassandra'
cluster = Cassandra.cluster
irb(main):002:0> require 'cassandra'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> cluster = Cassandra.cluster
Cassandra::Errors::NoHostsAvailable: All attempted hosts failed: 127.0.0.1 (Cassandra::Errors::IOError: Connection refused - connect(2))
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cassandra-driver-2.1.5/lib/cassandra/future.rb:570:in `get'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cassandra-driver-2.1.5/lib/cassandra/future.rb:363:in `get'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cassandra-driver-2.1.5/lib/cassandra.rb:211:in `cluster'
        from (irb):3
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

In the Cassandra.yaml file, I have set up the following:

```
cluster_name: 'MyCassandraCluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
  - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    parameters:
        - seeds: "172.17.0.2,172.17.0.3,172.17.0.4"
listen_address: IP of the host of the containers
rpc_address: <seed ip of this instance>
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the address or hostname of one of the Cassandra containers.

`Cassandra.cluster()` Defaults to localhost (127.0.0.1)

`Cassandra.cluster(hosts: ['172.17.0.2','172.17.0.3','172.17.0.4'])`

Or even better, just link your RoR container to cassandra (`--link cassandra:cassandra`) and you might be able to just do:

`Cassandra.cluster(hosts: ['cassandra'])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have created a simple ruby file as follows,and run. However I still get the same error:                                                             `` ``require 'cassandra'
 
cluster = Cassandra.cluster(
   username: 'root',
   password: 'MyTestMachine',
   hosts: ['172.17.0.2','172.17.0.3','172.17.0.4']
   )
 
keyspace = 'demo'
session = cluster.cluster(keyspace)' ``

Comment: What happened when you did ```Cassandra.cluster(hosts: ['cassandra'])```? That should resolve the IPs for you if you're linking the container. Also, you don't need all 3 IPs.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that. I am also experiencing the following when I try to run cqlsh from other two seed nodes:                   `[root@1c6cecf221bf /]# cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`